# Tools for high quality GIF files

Tags: image, video, github, gif, readme

I want to add some **GIF** files to my [README](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/tree/master/Examples).

Please help me create some **GIF** files:

- merge **PNG** images.
- convert a video to **GIF**.

I have seen some `60fps 4k gif` files, but I know they are fake.
For example 9gag using `<video>` tag with an **mp4** video source.

> I am not able to embed video directly to my README.
>
> I want only short (2-5 seconds) videos.

What is the best way to add animation to a github README file?

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic. Consider posting on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a tool to record your desktop screen to gif directly, I strongly recommend [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/) which is really easy and very useful.

Comment: I am using screen to GIF and it is awesome. Sometimes the colors mess up. Here is a [sample](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/raw/master/docs/Examples/images/sample.gif)

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi For that use case (low color count), try encoding with the encoder 2.0 of ScreenToGif.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMPEG with this method for converting videos to reasonable quality GIFs - http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html

quote:

```
#!/bin/sh

palette="/tmp/palette.png"

filters="fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos"

ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -vf "$filters,palettegen" -y $palette
ffmpeg -v warning -i $1 -i $palette -lavfi "$filters [x]; [x][1:v] paletteuse" -y $2
```

...which can be used like this:

```
% ./gifenc.sh video.mkv anim.gif
```

---

PNG files can be converted and merged in a GIF with imagemagick:

```
convert -loop 0 -delay 100 in1.png in2.png out.gif
```

Or with some online tools [like this one.](https://ezgif.com/maker)

---

But please keep in mind that GIF is not really intended or suited for large, high quality animations. With some trickery you can get it to display more than 256 colors, but it will dramatically increase file size. 4k 60fps GIFs will be very large to download and most likely cause performance problems. If you are planning to add multiple such GIFs to a single page, they probably will crash the browser or slow it down significantly for some visitors. That's why some sites now are using videos for what they call "GIFs".

Answer (score 1):

For maximum visual quality there's [gifski](https://gif.ski) encoder.

GIF theoretically supports maximum 100fps, but for backwards-compatibility reasons browsers won't play it at this rate. Some play at 33fps, some at 25 fps max.

GIF compression is awfully bad. Even the ideal case of solid color compresses poorly. GIF is able to encode only a small rectangle that differs between frames, so if it's a screencast where only mouse or text cursor moves, it may be tolerable file size (you can optimize that with [gifsicle/giflossy](https://kornel.ski/lossygif)), but otherwise avoid using high resolutions.